# ng2: reserve Original value if validation failed

Tags: validation, angular

I am trying to force the user to fill in the **description** when they update an item.  It validates, shows error message when validation fails, stops running execution and doesn't update an item.

Please see the series of screenshot below:
[image]

However, my item is still updated even if the validation fails.  It seems to me that since an object is reference in the memory, it's still updated even if it doesn't run `updateTodo()` method from the `Todoservice`.

Is it because I am just hardcoding my items just for the testing?  I am very new to Angular and I don't want to implement webAPIs at this point yet.

I tried to use `Object.assign({}, copy)` in `getTodoItem(id: number)` to clone and decouple my todoItem from the list but the error message showing that it's not observable.

How can I preserve the values of Objects in the list if the validation fails?  In real life application, Since we retrieve the data from the database (or webapi cache) whenever index/list component is navigated, this problem shouldn't occur.  Is my assumption right?

todoService.ts

```
    import { Itodo } from './todo'

const TodoItems: Itodo[] = [
    { todoId: 11, description: 'Silencer' },
    { todoId: 12, description: 'Centaur Warrunner' },
    { todoId: 13, description: 'Lycanthrope' },
    { todoId: 14, description: 'Sniper' },
    { todoId: 15, description: 'Lone Druid' }
]

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

    getTodoItems(): Observable<Itodo[]> {
        return Observable.of(TodoItems);
    }    

    getTodoItem(id: number): Observable<Itodo> {
        return this.getTodoItems()
            .map((items: Itodo[]) => items.find(p => p.todoId === id));

        //let copy = this.getTodoItems()
        //    .map((items: Itodo[]) => items.find(p => p.todoId === id));

        //return Object.assign({}, copy);
    }

    addNewTodo(model: Itodo): number {
        return TodoItems.push(model); // return new length of an array
    }

    updateTodo(model: Itodo) : number {
        let idx = TodoItems.indexOf(TodoItems.filter(f => f.todoId == model.todoId)[0]);        
        return TodoItems.splice(idx, 1, model).length; // return the count of affected item
    }
}
```

todo-edit.component.ts -- EditItem() is the main

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { Itodo } from './todo'
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "todo-edit.component.html"
})
export class TodoEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    todoModel: Itodo;
    private sub: Subscription;

    Message: string;
    MessageType: number;

    constructor(private _todoService: TodoService,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                let id = +params['id'];
                this.getItem(id);
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    getItem(id: number) {
        this._todoService.getTodoItem(id).subscribe(
            item => this.todoModel = item,
            error => this.Message = <any>error);
    }

    EditItem(): void {

        this.todoModel.description = this.todoModel.description.trim();
        if (!this.todoModel.description) {
            this.Message = "Description must not be blank.";
            this.MessageType = 2;
            return;
        }

        console.log('valid: update now.');
        let result = this._todoService.updateTodo(this.todoModel);

        if (result > 0) {
            this.Message = "An Item has been updated";
            this.MessageType = 1;
        }
        else {
            this.Message = "Error occured!  Try again.";
            this.MessageType = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Working Solution**

Object.assign it's the right method to use.  I was using it wrongly in the service to clone it.  You need to use it in your component, not in the service.

```
getItem(id: number) {
        //Object.assign clone and decouple todoModel from the ArrayList
        this._todoService.getTodoItem(id).subscribe(
            item => this.todoModel = Object.assign({}, item), 
            error => this.Message = <any>error);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation does not prevent updating items, it just checks actual values for validity. You should create copy of object for editing to be able to rollback changes. You can use `Object.assign({}, item)` or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`.